# Kinetic energy of rigid body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

A disc of mass mass $M $,radius $R$ is in state of pure rolling upon a horizontal plane as shown in figure. Find their kinetic energy of rigid body in the reference frame of P which is directly below the centre of disc, at a distance of $\frac{R}{4}$

[image]
K.E of B =Rotational Kinetic Energy+ Translational Kinetic Energy
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{MR^2}{2}+ \frac{MR^2}{16}\right){\omega}^2 + \frac{1}{2}MV^2$$
$$=\frac{9}{32}MV^2+\frac{1}{2}MV^2$$
But the answer says it is only $=\frac{9}{32}MV^2$.Why it only rotational and why translational kinetic energy is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the frame of reference of $P$ what do you see?
You see point $P$ not moving and the disc rotating at angular speed $\Omega$ about "fixed" point $P$.
Your first term is the kinetic energy of that rotation.

Comment: Same situation will be at c?

Comment: About $C$ the moment of inertia of the disc will be different.